# Eliminate Input, Start Timer At 2 minutes

Tags: javascript, timer

I currently have a timer that allows the user to select how long they want the timer's countdown to be. What I want to happen is just have the timer start at two minutes and begin counting down when the user clicks the start button. Here is my code

```
<body>
<div id="countdown"></div>
<div id="notifier"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function startTimer() {
userInput = document.getElementById('userTime').value;
if(userInput.length == 0){
    alert("Please enter a value");
} else {
var numericExpression = /^[0-9]+$/;
if(!userInput.match(numericExpression)){
alert("Please enter a number")
} else {

function display( notifier, str ) {
document.getElementById(notifier).innerHTML = str;
}

function toMinuteAndSecond( x ) {
return Math.floor(x/60) + ":" + x%60;
}

function setTimer( remain, actions ) {
(function countdown() {
   display("countdown", toMinuteAndSecond(remain));         
   actions[remain] && actions[remain]();
   (remain -= 1) >= 0 && setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);
})();
}

setTimer(userInput, {
10: function () { display("notifier", "Just 10 seconds to go"); },
 5: function () { display("notifier", "5 seconds left");        },
 0: function () { alert( "Time is up. Please Sumbit Vote.");       }
 }); 
 }  
 }
 }
 </script>
 Set Time Limit: <input type="text" id="userTime" />
<input type="button" value="Start" onclick="startTimer()" />
</body>
```

heres a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/grahamwalsh/0h9t65bs/

Comment: ur fiddle counts 2 seconds when i write 2, so u want to count from 2 mins when i write 2?

Comment: i dont want any imput at all, i just want it to be a 2 minute timer

Comment: Then hardcode the 2 mins instead of `document.getElementById('userTime').value` and drop off all the checking.

Comment: how do i do that sorry im pretty green

Comment: did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/0h9t65bs/1/) fiddle

```
function startTimer() {
  userInput = 120;
    if(userInput.length == 0){
        alert("Please enter a value");
    } else {
    var numericExpression = /^[0-9]+$/;

   function display( notifier, str ) {
    document.getElementById(notifier).innerHTML = str;
  }

  function toMinuteAndSecond( x ) {
    return Math.floor(x/60) + ":" + x%60;
  }

  function setTimer( remain, actions ) {
    (function countdown() {
       display("countdown", toMinuteAndSecond(remain));         
       actions[remain] && actions[remain]();
       (remain -= 1) >= 0 && setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);
    })();
  }

  setTimer(userInput, {
    10: function () { display("notifier", "Just 10 seconds to go"); },
     5: function () { display("notifier", "5 seconds left");        },
     0: function () { alert( "Time is up. Please Sumbit Vote.");       }
  }); 

}
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  startTimer();
});
```

[update](http://jsfiddle.net/0h9t65bs/2/) with the start button

added

```
 <input type="button" onclick="startTimer()" value="Start">
```

Comment: this is exactly what i want except i would like a start button, how would i go about adding that?

Comment: I've updated my answer with the link to the new fiddle, let me know

Comment: if my answer solve your problem remember to mark it as accepted to avoid that the question remain unanswered